# H5BP Build Script deployment

Tags: ant, build-automation, html5boilerplate

I'm trying to make my build script deploy to my development environment after build but i don't really get how to do that. If i just write the code directly in to project.xml i gets executed first in the process (even though project.xml is imported last in build.xml).

If i wrap the code in a target like this:

```
    <target name="-publish" depends="-copy">
    <!-- Copy to developing server -->
    <echo message="Publish to development server..."/>
</target>
```

It doesn't get executed at all. Depends on copy 'cause that seems to get executed last.

Comment: depends means: the target under depends is executed first when executing this target. It does not mean: this target is executed after any invokation of the depends.

Comment: yes, but how would you get target to run without touching build.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. To have the publishing stuff happen last you just specify it in the call like this:

```
ant build publish
```

I removed the dash from the target name. I guess the dash is to specify local target names only.